# How to handle errors inside React state setter function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, error-handling, react-context, react-state

In order to learn Context API, i'm trying to create a little react based ecommerce. I'm showing only relevant code. Please pay attention to function addItem in CartProvider.
As you can see, addProductToCart could throw. My question is: is this a good way to handle error? This is forcing me to handle errors in CartProvider but i think errors should be handled in ProductList component (and other components using CartContext).

**Cart module**

```
export function createCart() {
  return { items: [] }
}

export function addProductToCart(cart, product) {
  if (containsProduct(cart, product))
    throw new Error(`Cart already contains product ${product.id}`)

  return {
    ...cart,
    items: [...cart.items, { product, quantity: 1 }],
  }
}
```

**Cart Provider**

```
function CartProvider({ children }) {

  const [cart, setCart] = useState(createCart())

  function addItem(product) {
    setCart((cart) => {
      try {
        return addProductToCart(cart, product)
      } catch (err) {
        window.alert(err.message)
        return cart
      }
    })
  }

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={{ cart, addItem }}>
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

**Product listing**

```
export function ProductListing() {

   const { addItem } = useCart()

  function handleProductSelect(product) {
    addItem(product)
  }

  return (
        <ProductGrid
          products={SOMEPRODUCTS}
          onSelected={handleProductSelect}></ProductTable>
  )

}
```

I tried using setCart without a function and setCart with a state setter function. First approach allows error handling in other components (ProductList, CartDetails, etc)
Basically i would like to handle errors inside **handleProductSelect** function but i can't (because of state setter function)